# Does Android system send BOOT_COMPLETED intent multiple times to multiple receiver in one process or just once?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, ipc, boot

So basically I have two major functionality, A and B in my app, and they both do something on boot. So I made two BroadcastReceiver R1 and R2, both of which receives BOOT_COMPLETED intent. R1 has fairly complicated logic and handles functionality A. R2's logic is really simple and it handles B.

My problem is to decide if I should keep the code cleaner by keeping both Broadcast Receivers and make each of them listen to BOOT_COMPLETED intent, or if I should combine them to increase performance?

How big is the performance hit to receive two of the same intent instead of one? Will the send-receive-intent process happens once or twice in my app?

Also, is BOOT_COMPLETED sent only after the boot is completely finished, when user can launch apps?

Edit: After testing, the difference between receiving the same intents in the same app by two components vs. by one is roughly only a couple milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BroadcastReceivers are inherently independent of any Activities.

- If Activity A and Activity B are part of the same Application, I suggest combining them and using only one BroadcastReceiver.
- If they are for different apps and you plan on releasing the apps separately then they should remain two different entities.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for your response. A and B are in the same app. Do you think I still should combine these two even if that will make the code look much less cleaner?

Comment: From what you have described you can simply comment the section for Activity A and mark another section for B, keeping them separate but in the the BroadcastReceiver. (I would put B's code first, simply because you hint that A is a bit of mess.)  :)

Comment: Sure that will work. receiver1 actually has 4 different intents to listen to about Activity A, with some intents having multiple possible extra. That's why I am concerned about making code less readable.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the android:priority property in order to control these receiver, and make them execute in a specific order. The activity with the highest priority number will execute first. Something like this:

```
<activity
     android:name="First activity">
     <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
     android:name="Second activity">
     <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You have information about this [in this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

> android:priority The priority that should be given to the parent
>   component with regard to handling intents of the type described by the
>   filter. This attribute has meaning for both activities and broadcast
>   receivers: It provides information about how able an activity is to
>   respond to an intent that matches the filter, relative to other
>   activities that could also respond to the intent. When an intent could
>   be handled by multiple activities with different priorities, Android
>   will consider only those with higher priority values as potential
>   targets for the intent. It controls the order in which broadcast
>   receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with
>   higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The
>   order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for
>   asynchronous messages.) Use this attribute only if you really need to
>   impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want
>   to force Android to prefer one activity over others.
>
> The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a
>   higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater
>   than -1000 and less than 1000.
>
> Also see setPriority().

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Sam's answer...

> Also, is BOOT_COMPLETED sent only after the boot is completely finished, when user can launch apps?

It is sent around the time of when the keyguard appears. The key is "around the time". There are many boot-time receivers, and they will all receive the broadcast in an indeterminate order. Please make no assumptions about the precise time that you will get the broadcast or the precise state of the system at that point (e.g., may not have an Internet connection).

Comment: Yes I won't make assumption about that. What I want to ask though, is that if there is a performance hit, say one sec slower, to use two BRs, will user be waiting one more sec watching booting screen, or will user be actually able to do other things, but just slightly slower.

Comment: @JackWang: The home screen will appear while the boot-time receivers are getting their broadcasts.